# Phrasal prepositional verbs with objects and adverbs?

Tags: adverbs, phrasal-verbs

"We fixed Tom up quickly with new tools"

Hi guys, here's a doubt I have. 
Although I would more than likely place the adverb "quickly" between the subject "We" and verb "fixed" in this sentence to get "We quickly fixed Tom up with new tools", would this other order be grammatically correct and possible?

My question is basically the following:
Do these multi-word verbs that take 2 objects such as "let X in on Y / put X down to Y" accept an adverb between its two particles?

-We let John in quickly on our plan
-They put their bad performance down angrily to their slack preparation

I hope I made my doubt clear enough guys, 
Thanks in advance

John

Comment: It's much better to analyse "fix up" as a verb+prep construction rather than a multi-word verb.  In "We let John in quickly on our plan", there is only one object, i.e. "John". I'm not sure why you think there are two. We would more naturally say "We quickly let John in on our plan".

Comment: Hi BillJ, thanks for the response. I feel there are 2 objects, one being the Direct Object of the verb "let" which is "John" and the other being the Prepositional Object of " in on" which is "our plan".   I've read through this thoroughly so you can see where I'm coming from. Thanks again https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/british-grammar/phrasal-verbs-and-multi-word-verbs

Comment: I was referring to objects of the verb. The NP "our plan" is object complement of the prep "in" (not "in on"). The PP "on our plan" functions as complement of "in".

Comment: To be clear, the terms 'phrasal verb' and 'multi-word verb' are misleading. misnomers.In, for example, "We quickly fixed up Tom with new tools", it's not the whole expression "fixed up" that is a verb, but just the word "fixed". "Up" is a preposition, a separate constituent.

Comment: Per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=came+in+suddenly+and%2Csuddenly+came+in+and&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccame%20in%20suddenly%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuddenly%20came%20in%20and%3B%2Cc0), usage has changed significantly over time. A century ago, the sequence ***came in suddenly and*** was far more common than ***suddenly came in and***. But today they're more or less equally common - and the trend strongly suggests the ***post-positioned adverb*** (second) form will dominate in the future.